# NameError: global name 'program_stop_minutes' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code, I am using two different functions as the one is for select the data on a database and the other one is to use for move to the right via on keyboard control. I want to reduce the code to avoid adding the same line of codes in one function.

However, when I try this:

```
import move_right

class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):
    def GoRight(self):
        move_right.GoRight(self)
```

**I will get an error: NameError: global name 'program_stop_minutes' is not defined.**

The error are jumping on this line:

```
if program_stop_minutes == '05':
```

here is the move_right.py script where the error are found:

```
import datetime
import time
import xbmc
import xbmcgui


prog_id = 0
select_db_flag = False

def select_db(self):
     program_button = [elem.control for elem in self.program_buttons]
     programs_id = list()
     program_width = list()
     positions_X = list()
     positions_Y = list()

     for elem in program_button:
         programs_id.append(elem.getId())
         positions_X.append(elem.getX())
         positions_Y.append(elem.getY())
         program_width.append(elem.getWidth())
     programs_id = map(str, programs_id)
     posX = map(str, positions_X)
     posY = map(str, positions_Y)
     program_width = map(str, program_width)

     for pos_X, pos_Y, prog_id, prog_width in zip(positions_X, positions_Y, programs_id, program_width):
         if select_db_flag == True:
             profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
             conn1 = database.connect(profilePath)
             cur1 = conn1.cursor()
             cur1.execute('SELECT stop_date FROM programs where button_id=?', [prog_id])
             stop_date = cur1.fetchone()

             if stop_date is not None:
                 stop_date = str(stop_date[0])
                 stop_time = time.strptime(str(stop_date), '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
                 stop_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(stop_time))
                 program_stop_hours = stop_time.strftime('%H')
                 program_stop_minutes = stop_time.strftime('%M')
                 program_AM_PM = stop_time.strftime('%p')
                 half_hour = str(self.getControl(344).getLabel())
                 one_hour = str(self.getControl(345).getLabel())
                 one_hour_half = str(self.getControl(346).getLabel())
                 epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour, '%I:%M%p')
                 epg_time_2 = time.strptime(one_hour, '%I:%M%p')
                 epg_time_3 = time.strptime(one_hour_half, '%I:%M%p')


                  program_stop_time = program_stop_hours +':' + program_stop_minutes + program_AM_PM
                  program_stop_time = time.strptime(program_stop_time, '%I:%M%p')




def GoRight(self): 
    if int(pos_X) == 616 and int(prog_width) == 515:
        if program_stop_minutes == '05':
            programs_width = 399 
            self.getControl(int(prog_id)).setWidth(int(programs_width))
            nextprogram = int(prog_id) + 1
            nextprogramX = self.getControl(int(nextprogram)).getX()
            nextprogram_width = self.getControl(int(nextprogram)).getWidth()

            self.getControl(int(nextprograms)).setPosition(780, int(pos_Y))
            self.select_db()
            select_db_flag = True
```

I want to definate the `program_stop_minutes` when I want to call from `select_db` function to get the return output of timedelta, but I have no idea how to do this.

Can you please help me how i can definted the `program_stop_minutes` when I want to get the return output of timedelta when I want to call from `select_db` function?

Comment: You need to define `program_stop_minutes` outside of the local scope of any class/function. Currently it only exists within the scope of  `select_db` and is therefore not accessible to any other functions (including `GoRight`)

Comment: how i can define `program_stop_minutes` outside of the function and how i can get the return output of the `program_stop_minutes` when call `select_db` function? can you show me how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message explicitly states, `program_stop_minutes` is not a global variable. You define it within `select_db` and therefore it is *only* accessible within that function's scope. If you want to access it from other functions (such as `GoRight`), you will need to define the variable in the global scope *or* return the value from the function.

**Global Scope**

```
program_stop_minutes = 0

def select_db():
    global program_stop_minutes
    # Do stuff here then modify program_stop_minutes
    program_stop_minutes = stop_time.strftime('%M')

def GoRight():
    global program_stop_minutes
    if program_stop_minutes == '05':
        # Do some other stuff
```

**Returning Values from `select_db`**

If you instead want to return the information from `select_db` rather than using a global variable you can do the following:

```
def select_db():
    program_stop_minutes = stop_time.strftime('%M')
    return program_stop_minutes

def GoRight():
    program_stop_minutes = select_db()
    if program_stop_minutes == '05':
        # Do some other stuff
```

If you need *multiple* values returned from your function you can return then as a tuple. You can return any arbitrary number of arguments in this way.

```
def select_db():
    program_stop_minutes = stop_time.strftime('%M')
    epg_time_1 = time.strptime(half_hour, '%I:%M%p')

    return (program_stop_minutes, epg_time_1)

def GoRight():
    program_stop_minutes, epg_time_1 = select_db()
    if program_stop_minutes == '05':
        # Do some other stuff
```

As a side note, I'm not sure why you're using the `self` variable all over the place. Do you think these are all methods of a class? As you currently have it written, they are not. They are simply functions.

Comment: Thank you, I have define it but how I can get the return data from `select_db` when I call them?

Comment: @TimCullen You don't return anything from `select_db`

Comment: Thank you very much for this, can I use `epg_time_1` to get the return information when call `select_db` function at the same time when I use `program_stop_minutes` to get the return information?

Comment: thank you very much for this, problem are now solved! :)